# Having IStartup.earlyStartup() run without BundleActivator.start() being called although the Activator was properly set. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

To put it bluntly: is there any explanation for having an Eclipse plugin running its `IStartup.earlyStartup()` method but not `BundleActivator.start()` other than having a faulty(or no) `Activator` set on the Manifest file?

I quadruple checked and I'm positive I didn't incorrectly set the Activator in the Manifest, so I'm finding this behavior rather bizarre.

When running this plugin as part of a tool we're developing, the `Activator` is indeed ran although for some reason `earlyStartup()` doesn't, but when I try to run the same plugin through Eclipse, just the opposite happens.

From my understanding `BundleActivator.start()` always runs, so I'm finding this behavior rather intriguing. I'm pretty positive I've correctly set the `Activator` as if I try to type some other thing Eclipse complains "the given class is not on the class path".

Any clues on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the state of the bundle... if it is RESOLVED (as I believe it will be) then you have your answer. OSGi only calls the `BundleActivator.start()` method when the bundle is actually started! Eclipse unfortunately does not start the bundle before it calls the `IStartup` extension.

You can force OSGi to start the bundle by setting `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy` in your MANIFEST.MF. This is a flag to both Eclipse and OSGi which results in the bundle automatically starting when the first class is loaded from the bundle. Probably the class that is loaded will be your `IStartup` implementation.

However IMHO `Bundle-ActivationPolicy` unnecessarily complicates the OSGi lifecycle and I hate it...