# Is the name of an Eclipse plugin irrelevant as long as residing in the plugins/ directory and as long as its contents are valid?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I have been doing some experiments and it seems that at least in some cases it doesn't seem to be the case, that is -- it seems there are rules regarding the naming of plugin jars.

If my project has both an `BundleActivator.start()` and an `IStartup.earlyStartup()`, it seems that the latter will always run, regardless of the jar's name, while the first will only run in some cases. Why is this?

I've taken a quick look to the OSGi 4 spec and I couldn't find anything regarding bundle naming.

addenda: I'm not actually developing against Eclipse, but against an OSGi application that makes use of a lot of Eclipse plugins (p2 included, if this is in any way relevant for the issue).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the `BundleActivator.start()` and `IStartup.earlyStartup()`, I already answered this in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456359/having-istartup-earlystartup-run-without-bundleactivator-start-being-called), and you accepted the answer. Did you need further clarification? It would be better to ask for clarification on the original question rather than just repeat it.

Regarding bundle JAR file naming, OSGi does NOT care what the name of the JAR file is, which is why you could not find anything about it in the spec. In fact the bundle doesn't even have to be in a file, you could read it over the network or from anywhere you can get a `java.io.InputStream`.

However, Eclipse is built on top of OSGi and various parts of Eclipse **do** expect the name of the bundle JAR file to match the `Bundle-SymbolicName` of the bundle.

Since you say you are developing an OSGi application rather than an Eclipse application, it would be better to stick to pure OSGi mechanisms such as activators, DS components and services. Steer clear of Eclipse-isms like IStartup and the whole Extension Registry.